# lapply function to a list of .dbf files and return values in the corresponding column of each file

Tags: r, list, lapply

This is probably something really simple that I am missing but it is driving me mad.

I have imported .dbf files into a list like so:

```
library("foreign")
shp_files <- list.files("C:/Docs/DBfs", pattern = ".dbf", full.names = T)
shp <- lapply(shp_files, function(x){
read.dbf(x)
})
```

All of the files have identical column headings. I want to apply a function applies an equation to a column based on values from other columns.

For the sake of argument and to makes it simpler to explain lets say I have columns A, B and C and I want to add them together to calculate column D. From what I can see I need to use lapply to apply a function to all of the files like so:

```
Col_func <- function(x){
  X$D <- X$A + X$B +X$C
}

lapply(shp, Col_func)
```

This returns the values in the R window rather than to column D.

I've tried a few different combination such as:

```
Col_func <- function(x){
  X$A + X$B +X$C
}

shp$D <- lapply(shp, Col_func)
```

But nothing seems to be working.

It's probably something really obvious that I'm missing but I can't seem to find an answer (I'll probably kick myself).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say for sure because there's no reproducible example. In particular, providing a small example of `shp` would be helpful. But this might work:

```
Col_func <- function(X){
  X$D <- X$A + X$B +X$C
  return(X)
}
shp <- lapply(shp, Col_func)
```

This version of `Col_func` adds the `D` column to a given data.frame. `lapply` makes it do that for each data.frame in the list, outputting a new list of data.frames.

Comment: Yes! This works! I knew it would be something simple I was missing. Thank you!